# Character array initialization using for loop

Tags: c

Do we also have to initialize `\0`(NULL) character?

**Code:**

```c
char S[N];
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  scanf("%c", & S[i]); //Is it a wrong way to initialize char string character by character?
}
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  printf("%d  %c", i, S[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value of scanf, and probably also put a `\n` at the end of the printf format string

Comment: As mentioned in the answers below, this will work as long as you provide the length of you string, 'N' while operating on it. You cannot use standard string functions. The line termination is how the end of string is detected. Is this a bad way? yes if you are not careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, and you don't have to add the NUL (not NULL, it's ASCII) at the end because you're treating it as an array of N distinct characters and not as a string. If you wanted to `printf` it with `%s` or call `strlen` on it, then you'd have to add the NUL (and allocate N+1 characters for the array).

You should add `\n` at the end of your `printf` format string.

Note that you will have to type the N characters all on one line. If you press return after the first one, for example, the linefeed will be taken as the second character.

Comment: so if I use string.h lib functions then for a string of N length should I allot N+1 space to the Char str[]?

Comment: Yep, because you need the `\0` at the end. So to store "hello" you need `char[6]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work as long as there is enough data to be read from `stdin`. You should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect premature end of file. The output will be concatenated on a single line because you did not put a newline at the end of the format string.

Here is a much simpler way with `fread`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
#define N 100;
    char S[N];
    int n = fread(S, 1, N, stdin);
    if (n < N) {
        printf("read error: only %d bytes read\n", n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d  %c\n", i, S[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I literally answered the question about whether an array could be initialized character by character using `scanf`, but if you actually want to read characters into an array, this is obviously a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize a character array, write: `char S[N] = {0};` -- it will be initialized with zero characters, that could be used as a string terminator if you need them to.

If you need to read a string, just do that with `fread(buf, 1, N, stdin);`

All in all, your code might look like this:

```
char S[N] = {0};
fread(buf, 1, N, stdin);
```

Comment: This version may overflow the buffer, whereas the original could not